# While loop in bash script execute only once

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, stdin

I have a given shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=xenobot
SSH_KEY_LOCATION="~/.ssh/id_rsa"
FILE="server.info"
while read -r server_ip  package_type; do  
    if [[ $package_type == "deb" ]]; then
         echo "For $server_ip package type is $package_type"
         DPKG_FILE_PATH=$(ls ./src/dpkg/dpkg-*)
             DPKG_FILE=$(basename $DPKG_FILE_PATH)
             echo "$DPKG_FILE located at $DPKG_FILE_PATH will be transfered via SSH to server"
         scp ./src/dpkg/${DPKG_FILE} $USERNAME@$server_ip:/tmp
             ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${USERNAME} ${server_ip} "cd /tmp; sudo dpkg -i *.deb"
    elif [[ $package_type == "rpm" ]]; then
         echo "For $server_ip package type is $package_type"
             RPM_FILE_PATH=$(ls ./src/rpm/rpm-*)
             RPM_FILE=$(basename $RPM_FILE_PATH)
             echo "$RPM_FILE located at $RPM_FILE_PATH will be transfered via SSH to server"
         scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' ./src/rpm/${RPM_FILE} $USERNAME@$server_ip:/tmp
         echo "$RPM_FILE has been successfuly transfered to server!"
         ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${USERNAME} ${server_ip} "cd /tmp; sudo rpm -ivh --force $RPM_FILE"
    fi
done <"$FILE"
```

And I have following file server.info, from which previous shell script reads:

`213.136.80.123 rpm 213.136.91.102 rpm`

The problem with it, as it is execute only once from first line, and just stops there without executing the second line

I have tried just to print output from this server.info using the same while read -r and it seems that outputs just fine like this

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=xenobot
SSH_KEY_LOCATION="~/.ssh/id_rsa"
FILE="server.info"
while read -r server_ip  package_type; do  
    if [[ $package_type == "deb" ]]; then
         echo "For $server_ip package type is $package_type"
    elif [[ $package_type == "rpm" ]]; then
         echo "For $server_ip package type is $package_type"
    fi
done <"$FILE"
```

Output:

`213.136.80.123 rpm 213.136.91.102 rpm`

So it seems like it outputs two separate lines, however I do not know why it runs script only once in bigger example

Comment: No reason to use `ls`. Just `rpm_file_path=(./src/rpm/rpm-*)` to make `rpm_file_path` be an array.

Comment: The bug this question asks about is [BashFAQ #89](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089)

Comment: (btw, suggesting `rpm_file_path` instead of `RPM_FILE_PATH` is deliberate: all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the OS and shell; lowercase names are reserved for application use; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable)

Comment: Also, the quotes in `SSH_KEY_LOCATION="~/.ssh/id_rsa"` are wrong; putting the `~` inside the quotes stops it from being expanded. Use `ssh_key_location=~/.ssh/id_rsa`, or `ssh_key_location=~/".ssh/id_rsa"` -- but don't quote the tilde if you want it replaced with the path to your home directory. If you want something that _can_ be used in quotes, use `$HOME` (all caps because it's meaningful to POSIX-defined tools!) instead of `~`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different file descriptor for your list other than 0, 1, or 2 (in this case it's set to 3).

```bash
while read -r server_ip package_type <&3; do
    ...
done 3<"$FILE"
```

If that works, then what's going on here is that `ssh` -- being an interactive program -- is sucking up your STDIN input.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein about questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".